# How to debug issues with running shell scripts through Jenkins?

Tags: python, shell, jenkins

I am running a python script from Jenkins which is running a shell script which fails with below `Permission denied` error,I tried the following to debug the issue...

1.I am printing the `userid` with which the Jenkins job is running and it is the correct user

2.I ran the `pre_audit`command manually with the same userid on the Jenkins node and it works fine and there is no permission denied error

This error is only happening when running through Jenkins,am clueless as why this is happening?any pointers on why this is happening or how to debug further despite using the correct user which has the permission ?

```
2018-05-04 22:09:39 script.py submit_to_techteamweb    469    INFO    : userid:username

2018-05-04 22:09:39 script.py submit_to_techteamweb    471    INFO    : ./pre_audit --version 9.130.63.0.32.6.27 --chip 4364 --file /Users/username/FWintegration/techteam-automation/integration/release_notes.txt
2018-05-04 22:09:39 script.py submit_to_techteamweb    482    INFO    : Printing error...
2018-05-04 22:09:39 script.py submit_to_techteamweb    483    INFO    : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pre_audit", line 46, in <module>
    os.mkdir(submission_directory)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/SWE/Teams/techteam/Firmware/submissions/4364/9.130.63.0.32.6.27
```

Comment: Was the answer not helpful?

Comment: ya,I dont know what worked at that time, it keeps happening again and again ...basically pre_audit is a unix executable ..

Comment: I think it should be a new question then.

Comment: no, its the exact same question and problem...I think the root cause is the session that jenkins opens is different than the session I open on my machine, need a way to login through Jenkins

Comment: Is there any change compared to last time?

Answer (score 2):

Running shell script from jenkins required proper execution permissions. In your python script before executing your `script.sh` run following command:

`sh "chmod 755 script.sh"`

Comment: There is no issue in executing the shell script, the shell script tries to create. a folder in a network location which isn't working is the issue..any pointers on how to fix this?

Comment: I faced this error while executing shell script on mac. It worked fine when I execute it from Terminal but doesn't work when executed from jenkins. I solved it by granting the permission. Are you running script on mac?

Comment: Great! Enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

Is SELinux enabled on the machine? It could be that the Jenkins service is restricted (as it should be) from writing files outside the `$WORKDIR`. Creating files outside of the working directory is a Bad Idea™ in Jenkins.

Comment: The machine is a macPro ,how to check if SELinux is enabled on the machine ,if not how to enable it?